# Multidimensional array javascript with index starting not from 0

Tags: javascript

I need to fill multidimensional array but not from zeroth element but from i.e. 3rd, but got errors when trying to do that:

code is:

```
var matrix = [ [] ];
matrix[3][0] = 10;
print(matrix[3][0]);
```

then got error:
"Unable to set value of the property '0': object is null or undefined"

but when do same from zeroth element then it works:

```
var matrix = [ [] ];
matrix[0][0] = 10;
print(matrix[0][0]);
```

No errors here - why?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Because `matrix[3]` doesn't exist.

Comment: you have to initialize array from zeroth index. you can not access directly third index before initialize.

Comment: `var matrix = []; matrix[3] = [10]; print(matrix[3][0]);` JS doesn't have multidimensional arrays in the sense that, say, Pascal does - JS has arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your initial array:

```
var matrix = [ [] ];
```

you've got an array with a single zero-element array in it. At that point, `matrix[3]` is `undefined`.

You can initialize your matrix in several ways, depending on the nature of your problem. Here's one:

```
var matrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  matrix[i] = [];
```

Now you've got 10 rows, each one empty.

Comment: Well I have one more question. In case when I need to use more than one matrix array element then I have to initialize all of them in the loop or somwhere in the code initialize each matrix array element as array?

Comment: @user2968398 I'm not sure I understand you completely, but yes - before you use an element of any array *as* an array, it must be initialized. You don't have to do it ahead of time - you can check before trying to use it, and initialize it at that time.